# How to Install Packages has no installation candidate

Tags: package-management, dependencies, r, rstudio

My overall goal is to install rstudio. I have already installed r-base and r-base-dev. I am currently using Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety

When I try to use:

```
sudo dpkg -i rstudio-1.0.44-amd64.deb  b
```

I get the error:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     rstudio : Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 but it is not installable
               Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 but it is not installable
```

Trying `sudo apt-get install -f` does not install the packages.

Trying to directly  install the packages returns this error:

```
 Package libgstreamer0.10-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
 is only available from another source

 E: Package 'libgstreamer0.10-0' has no installation candidate
```

When I try searching Google for this package, I find a number of results like this:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/yakkety/amd64/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/yakkety/amd64/libgstreamer0.10-0

These links show that the current status of this file is "deleted."

My question is, what should I do when I encounter this situation? Should I report this a bug? Download an older version of the package?

Comment: My first response would be to look for an updated package.  The current version is 1.0.44, and is available from https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/

Comment: Thank you for noticing that, it was a copy paste error, I have tried both the newest version and a previous version of rstudio. I will edit my question to reflect the newer package.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to download older versions of the packages for Xenial. They appear to be work fine. This is the second time I have used this workaround in Yakkety, but am not sure if it is normal and acceptable or not.

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libgstreamer0.10-0
```